# Refresh UIPageViewController - reorder pages and add new pages

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` which I am providing page data for using an implementation of `UIPageControllerDelegate` and `UIPageControllerDataSource`.

It's all working fine, but I want to be able to add items to the page data and reorder the page data.

If a user has already got to the last of the pages, and then I add an item, they can't get to the next page because `viewControllerAfterViewController:` has already been called. If they scroll back one and then forward two they can get to the new page fine, so the data is setup correctly. How can I tell the `UIPageViewController` to refresh its store of what comes next?

Similarly I would like to reorder the collection that is backing the page view. But if I do this I'll get the same problem - the page view will think the next page is still what it was last time the current page was loaded.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to `reloadData:` on `UITableView`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to call `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`.

Also, in iOS 6, watch out if you're using UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll style, as there is a major caching bug if `animated:` is YES (see my discussion here: [UIPageViewController navigates to wrong page with Scroll transition style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939280/uipageviewcontroller-navigates-to-wrong-page-with-scroll-transition-style/12939384#12939384)).

Comment: Thanks - the setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: did it. Cheers for mentioning the bug too.

Answer (score 98):

I found a workaround to force `UIPageViewController` to forget about cached view controllers of neighboring pages that are currently not displayed:

```
pageViewController.dataSource = nil;
pageViewController.dataSource = self;
```

I do this everytime I change the set of pages. Of course this doesn't affect the currently displayed page.

With this workaround I avoid the caching bug and can still use `animated:YES` in `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`.

Comment: Interesting. Where do you unset and reset the dataSource? Before `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`, after it, or in the completion block? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I do this 0.01 seconds after didFinish in a dispatch_async block.

Comment: Thank you!  This method works when using a data source.  The accepted answer didn't work for me, at least on iOS 8.  Using "setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:" with the current view controller did not cause the data source to be called again.

Comment: tip: After you reset `dataSource` (a.k.a. `pageViewController.dataSource = nil;`) your method `-viewControllerBefore` and `-viewControllerAfter` will be called again. 
For restore the dataSource.

Comment: You need to reassign dataSource like above if `presentationCountForPageViewController` returns a dynamic value which might change after the refresh.

Comment: Double plus good. Why this is not documented -- inexcusable. Confirmed for iOS 10, Swift 2.3, Xcode 8

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not in iOS 10.3. The crash happens in setViewControllers(), so doing something 0.01 seconds afterward is too late. I tried this trick before calling setViewControllers(), and it doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work iOS 10 when you call `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` fast enough, still got wrong content offset.

Comment: And what if I also want to update the currently displayed page ?

Comment: @DJTano that's the purpose of `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`. Even though it asks for an array of view controllers, you usually send a single array (exception is a 2-element array if `spineLocation = .mid`) with the current VC.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz got it. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4 Version for reload of data of pageviewcontroller, to @theory's version.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if !completed { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.dataSource = nil
        self.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my complete implementation of @ortwin-gentz's answer in the didFinish delegate method in Swift 2, which works perfectly for me:

```
func pageViewController(
    pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool
) {
    if !completed { return }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        pageViewController.dataSource = nil
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm...Perfect..Thanks