# UIPageViewController update number of pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Hey guys I was looking to see if anyone knew how to update the number of pages in a UIPageViewController

A UIPageViewController has the method

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return count;
}
```

but that is called right at the beginning and there is no way to update it. 
With a table view you can call `[tableView reloadData]`

Does anyone know how to "reload" the data for a UIPageViewController?

Thanks guys

Comment: do you mean after switch the content view controller of pageViewController, then reload the content view controller's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the UIPageViewController's `setViewControllers` method:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)viewControllers 
             direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction 
             animated:(BOOL)animated 
             completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

Call this method on the UIPageViewController, and pass it the view controller you would like to present.

Comment: When I call that method it throws an exception and says:
The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition

Comment: You're right — looks like you should only pass a single view controller in that array. Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15325891/6658553

Comment: Okay thank you I just had to call that method with 1 and then let the methods for the previous and next view controller to handle that. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer worked for you, feel free to mark it as accepted so others can benefit if they have the same issue in the future!