# Incomplete delete animation for a single row horizontal UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Currently, I have a single row horizontal `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`

```
[All] [Calendar] [Home2] [Work3] [Work4] ... [Work8] [⚙]
```

The `UICollectionView`, is acting as a scrollable Tab layout navigation bar.

When user switch to `[⚙]` page, he is able to delete the tab before itself. In this case, during the 1st time of the delete operation, tab `[Work8]` will be removed.

Here's the straightforward code to achieve so.

---

https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/blob/debug/TabDemo/TabDemo/ViewController.swift#L144

```
func debug() {
    if tabInfos.count < 2 {
        return
    }
    
    let index = tabInfos.count-2
    tabInfos.remove(at: index)
    let indexPath = getIndexPath(index)
    self.tabCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    
    // TODO: Possible solution.
    /*
    self.tabCollectionView.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        let indexPath = self.getIndexPath(self.tabInfos.count-1)
        self.tabCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
        self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
    }
     */

    // Clear left/ right cached view controllers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624169/72437
    pageViewController.dataSource = nil
    pageViewController.dataSource = self

    // Don't forget to adjust the selection index.
    if index < self.selectedTabInfoIndex {
        selectedTabInfoIndex -= 1
    }
}
```

---

### Strange outcome

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wzgb4QErUes (Please refer to this video for complete deletion animation)

This is how it looks like before deletion

[image]

As you can see in the video, after the deletion of `[Work8]`, the left side tab (`[Work3]`) is not visible

[image]

My expected outcome is, `[Work3]` should be visible too immediately, without any additional action from user. I need to tap on the `UICollectionView`, move it abit, only all the tabs will appear

[image]

---

I prefer not to use `reloadData`, as

1. It will not preserve scroll position of `UICollectionView`.
2. It does not have animation.

Do you have any idea what is the root cause of this strange animation outcome?

Here's the complete source code to try it out - https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/tree/debug (Folder TabDemo)

Comment: It would be nice if you upload a simple reproducible project on git and link it here

Comment: I already posted it https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/releases/tag/debug (Under folder https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/tree/debug (Folder TabDemo)

Comment: I downloaded your demo project, compiled it with Xcode Version 12.0 beta 5 (12A8189h), and run it on the iPhone 11 Pro simulator. When I tap Delete in the Settings tab, the Work 3 tab is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure layout a bit differently - use explicit configuration instead of orthogonal behavior.

Here is fixed part. Tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7

[image: demo]

```
private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    configuration.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { (sectionNumber, env) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(44), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(44), heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 1
        return section
    }, configuration: configuration)
}
```

Comment: I thought I need to use `section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous` to achieve horizontal scrolling. I do not notice this `configuration.scrollDirection = .horizontal` technique. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

It has not been drawn yet because it was out of viewport when you clicked delete for Work8. This is typical for iOS.

You could force a redraw rather than a `reloadData`:

```
myViewOrComponent.setNeedsDisplay();
```

Comment: I try to call `setNeedsDisplay` in `UICollectionView`, after `deleteItems`, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a try with this, here you may require to handle scrollable contentSize and scrollPosition.

```
func debug() {
    if tabInfos.count < 2 {
        return
    }
    
    let index = tabInfos.count-2
    tabInfos.remove(at: index)
    var indexPath = getIndexPath(index)
    self.tabCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    tabCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layoutConfig()

    print(selectedTabInfoIndex)

    // Don't forget to adjust the selection index.
    if index < self.selectedTabInfoIndex {
        selectedTabInfoIndex -= 1
    }
    indexPath = getIndexPath(selectedTabInfoIndex)
    self.selectTab(selectedTabInfoIndex)
}
```