# Adding pagination to uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Adding pagination to uipageviewcontroller, is it possible?

I am a newbie and I want to load few pages of uipageviewcontroller at first and when user scrolls to 4th page I want to load another 5 pages.

Is it possible to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: just go through the link [uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro](https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

run the sample code given. this may help you

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati I have gone but I want to load 5 more that means want to update datasource

Comment: just see this post which give you the idea as you want: [how-can-i-add-new-pages-to-a-uipageviewcontroller-after-the-user-has-reached-the](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306096/how-can-i-add-new-pages-to-a-uipageviewcontroller-after-the-user-has-reached-the)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [FlexiblePageViewController](https://github.com/mu29/FlexiblePageViewController) (UIPageViewController for processing arbitrary data).
It supports pagination behavior.